# Can I install PC3-12800 RAM into an iMac with PC3-10600 slots?

Tags: memory

Also, is it ok to mix these? Like having 2x4 GBs of 10600 in two slots and 12800 in the other two?

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported (or recommended), but yes, the faster DIMMs will operate at the slower speed.

Comment: I see. Why is not recommended? I'm just trying to understand the situation better.